# Is there a way to convert a Windows Console app into a library, and then call one of the methods from a c# web application html link?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, crystal-reports

So I made a c# MVC Windows console application which implements crystal reports, to generate a pdf and then display it to the user. My goal is to implement this within my web application which uses MVC/Razor engine. Is it possible to package my reporting application into a library, reference that library within my web application, and finally have a hyper link's onclick generate the pdf?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what your code looks like right now.
I would not try to change a console application to a class library... it's way easier to move the code to a new library that is then available for any application project.

Generally speaking, you can just move any code that does the PDF generation to a different "new" project that is a class library. Both your Console application and your Web application can then reference that project, and access classes and their methods like that.

However, displaying the PDF is probably going to be different for a Web application. The most logical way would be to just have an endpoint return the PDF so that the user will download it (and maybe display it depending on the browser).